# Deserialize JSON to c# model

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I receive a json object like

```
 {
    "designKey": 7470,
    "title": "Test1",
    "note": "Test1",
    "createdBy": "username",
    "creationDate": "2020-01-24T20:47:28.297"   },  
 {
    "designKey": 7472,
    "title": "Test2",
    "note": "Test2",
    "createdBy": "username",
    "creationDate": "2020-01-24T23:20:44.207"   },   
 {
    "designKey": 7473,
    "title": "Test3",
    "note": "Test3",
    "createdBy": "username",
    "creationDate": "2020-01-24T23:39:03.99"   }
```

So I create model to deserialize like:

```
public class AssignDesignModel
    {
        public class DesignViewModel
        {
            public IList<DesignAssignViewModel> DesignAssignList { get; set; } = new List<DesignAssignViewModel>();
        }

        public class DesignAssignViewModel
        {
            public int DesignKey { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And I execute as:

```
 var rModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesignViewModel>(response.content);
```

But it throws an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Project.Models.AssignDesignModel+DesignViewModel' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or
>   a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection,
>   IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I search for similar questions but I can not find a solution. Regards

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesignAssignViewModel[]>` or if you want `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesignViewModel>`, make sure your json string has object format having a property `DesignAssignList` containing an array of `DesignViewModel` objects.

Comment: Make array of objects in your json and do what @RezaAghaei said.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's not very helpful.

Comment: @ViacheslavYankov Make **what** an array of objects?

Comment: @user1538301 as I see, your json is not formed as array. You should add [ ] like [{"prop1":""},{"prop2":""}]

Comment: I do it, now it dont throw any exception but it return 3 empty objects without any information @RezaAghaei

Comment: your json is not valid..... you need valid json.  got to https://jsonlint.com/ and post your json there to make sure it is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have `DesignViewModel` defined right now, your JSON would have to look like this:

```
{
    "DesignAssignList": [
        {
            "designKey": 7470,
            "title": "Test1",
            "note": "Test1",
            "createdBy": "username",
            "creationDate": "2020-01-24T20:47:28.297"
        },
        {
            "designKey": 7472,
            "title": "Test2",
            "note": "Test2",
            "createdBy": "username",
            "creationDate": "2020-01-24T23:20:44.207"
        },
        {
            "designKey": 7473,
            "title": "Test3",
            "note": "Test3",
            "createdBy": "username",
            "creationDate": "2020-01-24T23:39:03.99"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Good point but it's unlikely changing the format of the incoming JSON is an option.

Comment: @pseudocoder I hope it is... the JSON OP posted isn't JSON lol. (EDIT: though, in general, I do agree with your statement, I think it's worth enlightening the OP as to *why* what he's doing doesn't work, this may just be a simple "Doh!" moment for them as it was for me when I encountered this problem for the first time with ASP.NET a few years ago)

Comment: Totally true, structure of my model was bad... I just change remove `DesignAssignViewModel` and moved to `DesignViewModel` then change deserialize model to `IList` as: ` var rModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<DesignViewModel>>(response.content);` THANKS!

Comment: @Lion sounds like you used my answer and accepted this one!

Comment: @pseudocoder I would have to guess because while your answer solves the problem, mine explains the solution in a manner that allowed OP to arrive at it without having to copy any code; he now has the understanding to use your solution, my solution or any other proposed solution involving changes to his input or expected data model.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `AssignDesignModel` and `DesignViewModel` since they are not necessary.  The JSON file (almost) contains an array of objects you have defined as `class DesignAssignViewModel`, so I would call the deserialize like this:

Model:

```
public class DesignAssignViewModel
        {
            public int DesignKey { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        }
```

Deserialize:

`var rModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesignAssignViewModel[]>(response.content);`

That said, the incoming JSON is not formatted correctly as others have noted.  Therefore you should probably deal with that problem first.

Comment: Honestly, I will give you the upvote if you post the code changes you're recommending in your answer for OP to see; this is the *only* other acceptable solution to the problem at hand. (ETA: already gave upvote. please update answer for better quality)

Comment: The json posted it is not an array... it is not even valid json

Comment: @Darkonekt we are aware. Generally, when people post invalid JSON I reason about what the original JSON must have been, as anyone who is dealing with JSON should know that if it cannot be parsed, it won't work. Based on the question, proper JSON must be being used somewhere, or else OP wouldn't get as far as he has (He'd get a syntax error not a conversion error). But you are 100% right, I wouldn't let the invalid JSON stop you from providing an answer the OP might learn from (the lesson to learned for the OP isn't to write valid JSON, that's a lesson the runtime of his app will teach him)